# Concat reults when using case in statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I've seen this question arise and seen it answered numerous times but not exactly they way in which I need.  I have the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ia.UserName, ia.FirstName, ia.LastName, ia.`Password`,
CASE ipt.Code
    WHEN ipt.Code LIKE "%CORP_FILE%" THEN "ROLE_GAAP"
    WHEN ipt.Code LIKE "%RR_SUMMARY%" THEN "ROLE_RR"
END 
AS "role"
FROM 
    iCTrunk.Account ia, 
    iCTrunk.AccountGroup ig,
    iCTrunk.asscAccountAccountGroup iaaag, 
    iCTrunk.asscNodeAccountGroup ianag, 
    iCTrunk.asscNodeProjectType ianpt, 
    iCTrunk.ProjectType ipt 
WHERE ia.Id = iaaag.AccountId 
AND iaaag.AccountGroupId = ianag.AccountGroupId
AND ianag.NodeId = ianpt.NodeId 
AND ianpt.ProjectTypeId = ipt.Id
AND ia.UserName = '<some user here>'
```

There are 2 possible result sets from the query and most users will only return 1.  The issue is that if the user is an administrator then both query results will be returned.  I am trying to figure out a way to group_concat the "role" field so that I only get a single returned row. Since the row result is being read by an authentication login page it would be much easier to process a single returned result.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sample data and expected results is always a plus.  I'm not sure how you want to handle multiple ipt.codes; repeated; but given your use of distinct in the select I think you just want the distinct values w/ 0-2 "roles" listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to add the group_concat syntax and a group by; and I moved the distinct to be in the group_concat so you only get 0-2 results in the "Role" field.

```
SELECT ia.UserName, ia.FirstName, ia.LastName, ia.`Password`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE ipt.Code
    WHEN ipt.Code LIKE "%CORP_FILE%" THEN "ROLE_GAAP"
    WHEN ipt.Code LIKE "%RR_SUMMARY%" THEN "ROLE_RR"
END) AS "role"
FROM 
    iCTrunk.Account ia, 
    iCTrunk.AccountGroup ig,
    iCTrunk.asscAccountAccountGroup iaaag, 
    iCTrunk.asscNodeAccountGroup ianag, 
    iCTrunk.asscNodeProjectType ianpt, 
    iCTrunk.ProjectType ipt 
WHERE ia.Id = iaaag.AccountId 
AND iaaag.AccountGroupId = ianag.AccountGroupId
AND ianag.NodeId = ianpt.NodeId 
AND ianpt.ProjectTypeId = ipt.Id
AND ia.UserName = '<some user here>'
GROUP BY ia.UserName, ia.FirstName, ia.LastName, ia.`Password`
```

after the "END" in the case statement and before the ')' for group_concat, you could put...
  `ORDER BY ipt.code ASC SEPARATOR ','` if you want the names in a consistent order with a `,` separator.  just wanted to make sure you understand the group_concat() syntax a bit more.

Comment: that was super easy, thank you.  I was putting the Group_concat in the wrong place

Comment: Sometimes a picture is worth a 1000 words :P.  The distinct w/in the group_concat() eliminates the duplicates which would be caused by multiple records in the joins.  otherwise you would see the a role  listed once for each record in the resulting table joins.

Comment: Exactly!  Now that I see a working example it makes way more sense.  Thanks again